# Show the inequality $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin{t}}{t} dt-x + 1 < 0,~x >1$

Tags: calculus, integration

**Question:**

Show the inequality

$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t}~dt -x + 1 < 0, ~~~~~~~~~~~~x >1$$

**Attempted answer:**

This seems like a simple single-variable calculus solution without any advanced methods or arguments, perhaps combining insights from the behaviors of functions and their derivatives and some simple algebra. We probably do not need to evaluate the integral itself, although it is tempting.

Let us move over the $1$ to the $RHS$:

$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t} ~dt -x + 1 < 0 \Rightarrow \int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t} ~dt -x < -1$$

The following function:

$$\frac{\sin {t}}{t}$$

...is symmetrical around the $y$-axis and never goes above $1$. So that means that the derivative of following:

$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t} ~dt - x$$

is negative for all $x > 1$ since the derivative of $x$ is $1$ and the derivative of the integral never goes above $1$.

If it can be shown that the function:

$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t} ~dt - x$$

is decreasing on $x \in (1,\infty)$, we should be done. Is this just a natural consequence of the derivative being negative for all $x > 1$?

However, I am a bit stuck here. Is this the right path? How can this be given a complete solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t}~dt -x + 1$

Now Differentiate using Leibnitz Rule

$g'(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-1$

$\implies g'(x)<0\;$ because $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}<1$

$\implies g(x)$ is decreasing function.

So for $x>1$

$g(x)<g(1) \implies \int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t}~dt -x + 1<\int_{1}^{1} \frac{\sin {t}}{t}~dt -1 + 1$

$\implies \int_{1}^{x} \frac{\sin {t}}{t}~dt -x + 1<0$.